# jQuery validation within fieldset

Tags: jquery, validation

I have multi page which need to validate. how to make it validate only for the first page when click continue? if possible i dont want to directly use like this,

```
$('.spanEmail').addClass('showError').removeClass('hideError')
```

i want to make dynamic code to use to other template. Also I cannot use jquery validate plugin because in code have select list use ul li method need to follow standard style from requirement.

And how to use keyup function when user start typing in input field, i want to add again hideError class for specific field. Thanks in advance.

here is my code and here for jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jCos/Lomd9rkr/

html

```
    <form id="my-form">
  <fieldset id="A">
    <div class="mwf-input">
      <label class="mwf-label" for="email-add">
        email</label>
      <input id="email-add" name="email-add" class="mwf-text line ptm required " type="email">
      <span id="spanEmail" class="required hideError">Please Enter Email Address</span>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Continue" id="next-button" class="next" name="next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="B">
    <label class="mwf-label" for="fname">
      First name</label>

    <div class="mwf-input">
      <input id="fname" name="fname" class="mwf-text line ptm " type="text">
    </div>
    <label class="mwf-label" for="lname">
      Last name</label>
    <span class="mwf-required">*</span>
    <div class="mwf-input">
      <input id="lname" name="lname" class="mwf-text line ptm required" type="text">
      <span id="spanLname" class="required hideError">Please enter Last Name</span>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#next-button").click(function() {
      var fields = $('input.required');
      for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if ($(fields[i]).val() != '') {
          $('#my-form').each(function() {
            $(this).find('span.required').addClass('hideError').removeClass('showError');
          });
          $('#B').show();
          $('#A').hide();
        } else {
          $('#my-form').each(function() {
            $(this).find('span.required').addClass('showError').removeClass('hideError');
          });
        }
      }
      });
  });
```

css

```
   #B,
.hideError {
  display: none;
}

.showError {
  display: block;
  color: #DC3C14;
}
```

**Update**

I just update my jQuery to search input in each fieldset which has required class

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#next-button").click(function() {
    var fields = $('#A input.required');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      if ($(fields[i]).val() != '') {

        $('#' + fields[i].id).siblings('span').addClass('hideError').removeClass('showError');
        $('#B').show();
        $('#A').hide();
      } else {
        $('#' + fields[i].id).siblings('span').addClass('showError').removeClass('hideError');

      }
      }

});

//function click for submit button
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var fields = $('#B input.required');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      if ($(fields[i]).val() != '') {
//add and remove class siblings with input field only for <span>
        $('#' + fields[i].id).siblings('span').addClass('hideError').removeClass('showError');

      } else {
        $('#' + fields[i].id).siblings('span').addClass('showError').removeClass('hideError');

      }
      }

});

//function keyup clear error
$("input").keyup(function() {
var fields = $('input.required');
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
if ($(fields[i]).val() != '') {
    $('#' + fields[i].id).siblings('span').addClass('hideError').removeClass('showError');


} else {
  $('#' + fields[i].id).siblings('span').addClass('showError').removeClass('hideError');
}
}
});
});
```

As u can see, it still not dynamic way, because i directly give the fieldset ID in var fields, how to pass the fieldset id in this var fields?

Also how to get button id when user click? in my jQuery above, i just write same  logic for different button.

here the update jsfiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/jCos/Lomd9rkr/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, this is the solution:

here for the demo [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jCos/Lomd9rkr/11/)

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

  var buttons = $('input[type="button"]');
  buttons.click(function() {
    var thisFieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset");
    $("input", thisFieldset).trigger("keyup")
    if ($(".showError", thisFieldset).length === 0) {
      var nextFieldset = thisFieldset.next().show()
      thisFieldset.hide()
      if (nextFieldset.length === 0) alert("now submit via ajax!")
    }
  })


  $('input.required').keyup(function() {
    var empty = $(this).val() == "";
    $(this).next().toggleClass("hideError", !empty).toggleClass("showError", empty)
  });
  var valid_email = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  $('input[type="email"]').keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val()
    var bad = !val.match(valid_email);
    $(this).next().toggleClass("hideError", !bad).toggleClass("showError", bad)
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used html5 form validation and jquery. Hope it helps..

```
        <form id="my-form">
      <fieldset id="A">
        <div class="mwf-input">
          <label class="mwf-label" for="email-add">
            email</label>
            <input id="email-add" name="email-add" class="mwf-text line ptm required " required="required" type="email">
          <span id="spanEmail" class="required hideError">Please Enter Email Address</span>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Continue" id="next-button" class="next" name="next">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="B">
        <label class="mwf-label" for="fname">
          First name</label>

        <div class="mwf-input">
          <input id="fname" name="fname" class="mwf-text line ptm " type="text">
        </div>
        <label class="mwf-label" for="lname">
          Last name</label>
        <span class="mwf-required">*</span>
        <div class="mwf-input">
          <input id="lname" name="lname" class="mwf-text line ptm required" required="required" type="text">
          <span id="spanLname" class="required hideError">Please enter Last Name</span>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>



        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#next-button").click(function() {

                    var isValid = $('#email-add')[0].checkValidity();
                    console.log(isValid);
                    if(!isValid) {
                        $("#spanEmail").addClass('showError').removeClass('hideError');
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#spanEmail").addClass('hideError').removeClass('showError'); 
                        $('#B').show();
                        $('#A').hide();
                    }

                    });
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks @T.Shah for you answer, but i want to find all input field with the required class then do the logic on that with dynamic way, not directly refer to the tag span ID. It is possible?

Comment: Look at these - might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677312/jquery-validate-individual-fieldsets and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723300/jquery-validation-per-multiple-fieldsets-how-to-use-different-event-to-trigger

Comment: Thanks again, will try to figure out from the link you provide.